# Using $(this) in JQuery .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, this, addclass

never asked question before as I can usually find the answer by hunting around here, but this has me stumped. I don't pretend to be any sort of JS/JQ expert, but I'm reasonably familiar with both. What I am trying to do is set a predefined CSS class to a group of text input elements within a form (The version of Django I am using unfortunately is not able to do this for me, and its not currently possible for me to upgrade as I don't have the time):

```
function setBsCss() {
var fields = $("input[type='text'], textarea").serializeArray();
jQuery.each(fields, function(i, field){
    if ((this.name != "csrfmiddlewaretoken") && (this.name.indexOf("recaptcha") == -1)) {
        $(this).addClass('someclass');
    }
});
```

}

I'm not getting any errors, but the class is simply not being added to the elements. I could change the code and simply use a name or an ID selector, but I'd prefer to apply the class to the object itself if possible.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You want to addClass to dom elemnts but using serializeArray() making fields array and not jq object selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm the behaviour, but I don't understand it.

To solve this, you can avoid converting the jQuery object to an array and just use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) instead of [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```js
$("input[type='text'], textarea").each(function (i, field) {
    if ((this.name != "csrfmiddlewaretoken") && (this.name.indexOf("recaptcha") == -1)) {
        $(this).addClass('someclass');
    }
});
```

See full [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bW8hW/)

*Update:*

The problem lies in the [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

> **.serializeArray()**
>   **Description**: Encode a set of form elements as an array of names and values.
>   The .serializeArray() method creates a JavaScript array of objects, ready to be encoded as a JSON string.

`serializeArray()` does *not* create an array of DOM elements, but only an array of `name`/`value` pairs. So, `this` refers to an object

```js
{
    name: "other",
    value: "somevalue"
}
```

which does not behave as expected, when used with `addClass()`.

Comment: Seems so simple now! You're absolutely right. Thanks very much for the clarification, got it working :)